Vertex AI Estado:429 Codigo de Error:8 ¿Qué puedo hacer?
Mensaje de error: “Resource exhausted. Please try again later. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/quotas#error-code-429 for more details.”
Estado: 429 Código de error: 8
Ya mire en las cuotas y no se ha utilizado ni el 5%, sin embargo, me aparece este error, ¿Qué puede ser?
Muchas gracias.
Estoy utilizando la función de capturar los eventos de un video de youtube, por cierto, me dice que mi límite de tokens de salida es de 8192, y que, por ejemplo hay videos de más de 300.000 tokens, sin embargo, a veces me funciona y a veces no.
Dar solución al error o al menos entender que está ocurriendo.
